# Intellij project opening directory above project

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I feel kind of silly asking this but I've been poking around and I don't know what is causing it. I have a directory structure that has a number of projects in it, it looks like this:

`projects_root/project1
projects_root/project2
projects_root/project3`

When I open *any* of these projects with Intellij it instead opens up the `projects_root` directory, so that all the projects in the directory are opened under my project tab. This is annoying as it clutters up my project view and it's causing some issues with my debug configurations etc. The strange thing is this was working fine until yesterday, that is opening `project1` would open at the root of `project1` instead of `projects_root`. I've changed no settings, the behaviour seemed to just start out of the blue. Has anyone seen behaviour like this before? Could anyone recommend a fix for this?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: How are you importing `project1`? Does your `build.xml` have declaration for other dependencies? You can also do `Project Right Click > Module Settings`  and remove other modules and they shouldnt re-appear unless you import project again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the content root of your IntelliJ project is incorrect. I can't tell you the cause for why this happened but you should be able to fix the content roots without needing to recreate each of the projects.

For each project, open up the respective IntelliJ project and follow the steps for [removing a content root](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html) for all of the non-applicable content. E.g., for `project1` remove `projects_root/project2` and `projects_root/project3`.